# Monitoring and Flushing a PubSub Batch Publisher Queue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

In the [Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) for Google PubSub, is it possible to monitor the size of of a Batch Publisher's queue and flush it on demand?

I am developing a Node/Express service that uses a PubSub batch publisher to push application events into a PubSub topic. I would like to set up some metrics and alerts on the batch publisher's queue size. In addition, when an instance of this service receives a SIGTERM signal, I’d like to run a shut down procedure in order to ensure that messages are not lost. Ideally I’d like to flush any messages in the publisher’s queue when this happens, but at the very least I’d like to be able to know which messages, if any, remain. This service will be running inside of Google App Engine, which has some documentation on [lifecycle events](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#lifecycle_events)  but nothing specific to PubSub, at least that I've been able to find.

I’ve read through the PubSub node client docs and examples and didn’t see anything that mentioned these features. I did notice that the Publisher object has a [*publish_* method](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/src/publisher.js) to forcefully publish the queue, but that is explicitly called out as a private method not to be used externally, so I’m hesitant to make use of it.

Does anyone have experience with monitoring and flushing a PubSub batch publisher queue? Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have more control on batching queue. But there is a public Feature Request [[1]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110512420) for more transparent tracking (i.e. logging, monitoring) of the message life cycle and I added your use case to the request.